# Add more hash to existing hash script in multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I've php script files that store password to MySQL using md5 hash

Here's some of existing query code in that php files

```
some query part....,MD5('$pass'),.....some query part
```

Some script has lowercase md5

```
some query part....,md5('$pass'),.....some query part
```

My goal is to add another hash to existing code, like, sh1

So the expected query script should be like this

```
some query part....,sh1(MD5('$pass')),.....some query part
```

at the end, the current md5 isn't matter if it's in lowercase or uppercase

I've tried to use sed to replace that files but no luck

```
sed -i 's/md5\(.*\)/sha1\(md5\(.*\)\)/gI' *.php
```

Is there anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i 's/\bmd5([^()]*)/sha1(&)/gI' *.php
```

The POSIX BRE expression matches:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `md5(` - an `md5(` substring
- `[^()]*` - 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `)` - a `)` char.

The `sha1(&)` replacement pattern replaces the match woth `sha1(`, then the match value, and then `)`.

See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/QbLzP6):

```
s='some query part....,MD5('"'"'$pass'"'"'),.....some query part
some query part....,md5('"'"'$pass'"'"'),.....some query part'
sed 's/\bmd5([^()]*)/sha1(&)/gI' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
some query part....,sha1(MD5('$pass')),.....some query part
some query part....,sha1(md5('$pass')),.....some query part
```